# Docker run with pseudoTTY (-t) gives instant stdout, buffering happens without it

Tags: python, docker

I have a python package which I am running inside a container. The Dockerfile says:

```
FROM frolvlad/alpine-python3
RUN apk --no-cache add ca-certificates
COPY ./ /app/
RUN cd app && python3 setup.py install
```

Now, once the image is built, when I run it using this command ...

```
docker run --env-file ./envfile myimg sh -c 'myscript "$username" "$password"'
```

... it takes over a minute to see any sort of std output. I also have to stop the container from another terminal (Ctrl+C does nothing).

But when I run the image using

```
docker run -t --env-file ./envfile myimg sh -c 'myscript "$username" "$password"'
```

(i.e. adding `-t`), it behaves as expected (some stdout every 5 seconds or so).

What is the reason for this behavior? I don't know exactly what `-t` does to cause this, as I was not able to find much documentation about it.

Comment: -t allocates a tty, it may be useful, and -i means interactive

Comment: [`PYTHONUNBUFFERED`](https://docs.python.org/2/using/cmdline.html#envvar-PYTHONUNBUFFERED) may help in the case of running python scripts.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is standard Linux stdio behavior.

If you are outputting to a file or filehandle (such as stdout), it is buffered in 4k chunks. This is to optimize I/O handling.

If the destination is a tty (terminal), the buffer is line-based.

Ref: https://www.turnkeylinux.org/blog/unix-buffering

> Behind the scenes, the culprit is Unix stdio buffering, as implemented on Linux by glibc which is a system library that most programs implemented in C use to handle basic stuff (e.g., IO).
>
> The idea behind Unix buffering is to improve IO performance by batching together IO calls at the application level (AKA userland) and thus minimizing relatively expensive kernel level read/write operations.
>
> By default writes to stdout pass through a 4096 byte buffer, unless stdout happens to be a terminal/tty in which case it is line buffered.

Comment: So that means that a simple script which echoes to stdout will change its "printing behavior" in those cases? `./foo` `./foo > outfile`. The latter will buffer? I did not know that the OS can detect the destination of stdout, good to know.

Comment: @MartinMelka Assuming that first case is run in a terminal session, then yes it would line-buffer instead of using 4k block buffering.