# Skyfield.api loader behaves differently in docker container

Tags: python, docker, skyfield

I wish to specify to Skyfield a download directory as documented here :

http://rhodesmill.org/skyfield/files.html

Here is my script:

```
from skyfield.api import Loader
load = Loader('~/data/skyfield')
# Next line downloads deltat.data, deltat.preds, Leap_Second.dat in ~/data/skyfield
ts = load.timescale()
t = ts.utc(2017,9,13,0,0,0)
stations_url = 'http://celestrak.com/NORAD/elements/stations.txt'
# Next line downloads stations.txt in ~/data/skyfield AND deltat.data, deltat.preds, Leap_Second.dat in $PWD !!!
satellites = load.tle(stations_url)
satellite = satellites['ISS (ZARYA)']
```

**Expected behaviour (works fine outside docker)**

The 3 deltat files (*deltat.data*, *deltat.preds* and *Leap_Second.dat*) are downloaded in *~/data/skyfield* with `load.timescale()` and *stations.txt* is downloaded at the same place with `load.tle(stations_url)`

**Behaviour when run in a container**

The 3 deltat files get downloaded twice :

- one time in the specified folder at the call `load.timescale()`
- another time in the current directory at the call `load.tle(stations_url)`

This is frustrating because they already exist at this point and they pollute current directory. Note that *stations.txt* end up in the right place (*~/data/skyfield*)

**If the container is ran interactively**, then calling `exec(open("script.py").read())` in a python shell gives a **normal behaviour** again. Can anyone reproduce this issue? It is hard to tell wether it comes from python, docker or skyfield.

The dockerfile is just these 2 lines:

```
FROM continuumio/anaconda3:latest
RUN conda install -c astropy astroquery && conda install -c anaconda ephem=3.7.6.0 && pip install skyfield
```

Then (assuming the built image is tagged astro) I run it with :

```
docker run --rm -w /tmp/working -v $PWD:/tmp/working astro:latest python script.py
```

And here is the output (provided the folders are empty before the run):

```
[#################################] 100% deltat.data
[#################################] 100% deltat.preds
[#################################] 100% Leap_Second.dat
[#################################] 100% stations.txt
[#################################] 100% deltat.data
[#################################] 100% deltat.preds
[#################################] 100% Leap_Second.dat
```

**EDIT**

Adding -t to docker run did not solve the issue but helped to even illustrate it better. I think it may come from Skyfield because some recent issues on github seem quite similar although not exactly the same.

Answer (score 1):

The simple solution here is to add `-t` to your `docker run` command to allocate a pseudo TTY:

```
docker run --rm -t -w /tmp/working -v $PWD:/tmp/working astro:latest python script.py
```

What you are seeing is caused by the way the lines are printed and buffering of non-TTY based stdout. The percentage up to 100% is likely printed on a line without newlines. Then after 100% it is printed again with a newline. With buffering, this causes it to be printed twice.

When you run the same command with a TTY, there is no buffering and the lines are printed realtime so the newlines actually work as desired.

The code path isn't actually running twice :)

See [Docker run with pseudoTTY (-t) gives instant stdout, buffering happens without it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42230153/docker-run-with-pseudotty-t-gives-instant-stdout-buffering-happens-without-i) for another explanation (possibly better than mine).

Comment: This does help to sort out the prints but I still have the issue regarding the duplicate downloads. This following code line re-download the 3 mentionned files in the current folder when it should go get them in data/skyfield where they already exist! `satellites = load.tle(stations_url)`

Comment: OK. You mean, they are not downloaded twice, but they are not downloading / checking the existing files in the the correct location? I mis-understood the original issue.

Comment: Not quite, but thanks for your answer, I edited the question to make it more clear. Actually, I think the issue may come from skyfield, maybe somewhere in this file https://github.com/skyfielders/python-skyfield/blob/master/skyfield/iokit.py but I'm not so sure because if I do not use docker, it works as expected... this is really strange, I hope someone ca reproduce the problem